# Erro entre conta em 2 tabelas laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.6

Desculpem a minha não experienciaria em laravel, estou iniciando os estudos e preciso consultar uma tabela Mysql de acordo com o valor de outra tabela ex.:

```
Tabela Sessões 
|   id   |   nome   |
|   1    |   João   |
|   2    |   Fabio  |
|   3    |   Maria  |

Tabela Produtos
| id | sessao_id | nome       |
| 1  | 1         | Computador |
| 2  | 1         | Televisor  |
| 3  | 2         | Carro      |
```

Model Sessões

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Produtos;
class Sessoes extends Model
{
protected $id = 'id';

public function produtos(){
    return $this->hasMany(Produtos::class);
}
}
```

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Site;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Categoria;
use App\Models\Sessoes;
use App\Models\Produtos;
class SiteController extends Controller
{
public function listaProdutos(){

    $idsessao = Sessoes::where('id', '2')->get()->first();

    $produtos = $idsessao->produtos;
    foreach ($produtos as $prod) {
        echo $prod->nome;
    }
}
}
```

Onde posso estar errando ou deixando de fazer algo?

Esta me retornando o seguinte erro

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'produtos.sessoes_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `produtos` where `produtos`.`sessoes_id` = 2 and `produtos`.`sessoes_id` is not null)

Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Se não explicar o erro, não saberemos o que está errando.

Comment: Editado com o retorno do erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua tabela de produtos a chave estrangeira foi nomeada de **sessao_id**. Entretanto, o Laravel está fazendo a execução do SQL procurando por **sessoes_id**. Perceba que no seu banco a chave está no SINGULAR e o Laravel está procurando no PLURAL.

Altere seu código para:

```html
public function produtos(){
    return $this->hasMany(Produtos::class, 'sessao_id', 'id');
}
```

[Fonte](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one), customizar nome da chave estrangeira e primária.

Comment: Valew Vinicius Carra, era isso mesmo! Muito Obrigado!